# Why do we need ORG 0x7c00 at the beginning of a bootloader?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, bootloader, bios

In every bootloader code that I've seen, there's this line "ORG 0x7c00" at the beginning of the file. As far as I know, BIOS will put this code at address 0x7c00.

So what is the reason of doing the "org 0x7c00"? Isn't it true that if the first instruction is loaded into 0x7c00, the counter will automatically start from there? Isn't the address of every instruction 0x7c00 + offset anyway?

Comment: `org 0x7c00` is needed to tell the assembler that this is the load address.  If you don't do this, it'll assume the load address is `0x0000`.

Comment: Also note that due to real mode addressing you may be running from `0:7c00` or `7c0:0` (or any other mapping but in practice you will only see these two). You should reload `CS:IP` with your preferred values and that means you may very well use `ORG 0` (or leave it at the default).

Comment: @fuz so what you mean is the bios doesn't know that i'll load the bootloader to 0x7c00, instead the bootloader tells it to do so?

Comment: @banana3227 Again: the BIOS knows, but the assembler doesn't.  The assembler needs to know the load address so it can compute addresses correctly.  This BIOS does not care at all how you write your bootloader, it just loads it to `7c00` and jumps to the beginning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the following code:

```
org 0x7c00

bits 16

jmp somefunction

somefunction:
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax

cli

lgdt[gdtr]

mov eax, cr0
or al, 1
mov cr0, eax

jmp 0x08:protectedMode
                        
bits 32

protectedMode:

mov ax, 0x10
mov ds, ax

hlt

gdt_start:
        dq 0x0
gdt_code:
        dw 0xFFFF   ;limit 0-15
        dw 0x0      ;base 0-15
        db 0x0      ;base 16-23 
        db 10011010b    ;pr, privi (2), s, ex, dc, rw, ac 
        db 11001111b    ;gr, sz, limit 16-19
        db 0x0      ;base 24-31
gdt_data:
        dw 0xFFFF
        dw 0x0
        db 0x0
        db 10010010b
        db 11001111b
        db 0x0  
gdtr:
        dw 24
        dd gdt_start

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Assemble with `nasm -fbin boot.s -oboot.bin`. You can disassemble easily the first part (16 bits part) of boot.bin with ndisasm to see what happens. Run the command `ndisasm -b16 boot.bin` and see the result:

```
00000000  EB00              jmp short 0x2
00000002  31C0              xor ax,ax
00000004  8ED8              mov ds,ax
00000006  FA                cli
00000007  0F0116387C        lgdt [0x7c38]
0000000C  0F20C0            mov eax,cr0
0000000F  0C01              or al,0x1
00000011  0F22C0            mov cr0,eax
00000014  EA197C0800        jmp 0x8:0x7c19
00000019  66B810008ED8      mov eax,0xd88e0010
0000001F  F4                hlt
00000020  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000022  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000024  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000026  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000028  FF                db 0xff
00000029  FF00              inc word [bx+si]
0000002B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000002D  9ACF00FFFF        call 0xffff:0xcf
00000032  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000034  0092CF00          add [bp+si+0xcf],dl
00000038  1800              sbb [bx+si],al
0000003A  207C00            and [si+0x0],bh
0000003D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000003F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000041  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000043  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000045  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000047  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000049  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000004B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000004D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000004F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000051  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000053  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000055  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000057  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000059  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000005B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000005D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000005F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000061  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000063  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000065  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000067  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000069  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000006B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000006D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000006F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000071  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000073  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000075  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000077  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000079  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000007B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000007D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000007F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000081  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000083  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000085  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000087  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000089  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000008B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000008D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000008F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000091  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000093  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000095  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000097  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000099  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000009B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000009D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000009F  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000A1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000A3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000A5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000A7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000A9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000AB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000AD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000AF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000B1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000B3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000B5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000B7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000B9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000BB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000BD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000BF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000C1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000C3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000C5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000C7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000C9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000CB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000CD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000CF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000D1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000D3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000D5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000D7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000D9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000DB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000DD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000DF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000E1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000E3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000E5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000E7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000E9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000EB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000ED  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000EF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000F1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000F3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000F5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000F7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000F9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000FB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000FD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000000FF  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000101  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000103  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000105  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000107  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000109  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000010B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000010D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000010F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000111  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000113  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000115  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000117  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000119  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000011B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000011D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000011F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000121  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000123  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000125  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000127  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000129  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000012B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000012D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000012F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000131  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000133  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000135  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000137  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000139  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000013B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000013D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000013F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000141  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000143  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000145  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000147  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000149  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000014B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000014D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000014F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000151  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000153  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000155  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000157  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000159  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000015B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000015D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000015F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000161  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000163  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000165  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000167  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000169  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000016B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000016D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000016F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000171  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000173  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000175  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000177  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000179  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000017B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000017D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000017F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000181  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000183  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000185  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000187  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000189  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000018B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000018D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000018F  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000191  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000193  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000195  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000197  0000              add [bx+si],al
00000199  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000019B  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000019D  0000              add [bx+si],al
0000019F  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001A1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001A3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001A5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001A7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001A9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001AB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001AD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001AF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001B1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001B3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001B5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001B7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001B9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001BB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001BD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001BF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001C1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001C3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001C5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001C7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001C9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001CB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001CD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001CF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001D1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001D3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001D5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001D7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001D9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001DB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001DD  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001DF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001E1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001E3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001E5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001E7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001E9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001EB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001ED  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001EF  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001F1  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001F3  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001F5  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001F7  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001F9  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001FB  0000              add [bx+si],al
000001FD  0055AA            add [di-0x56],dl
```

A short jump like a jmp to a label is relative. This means that the jump will work even if you don't have the org directive. In the meantime, a far jump is absolute. It jumps to an address specified as a segment:offset pair. The org directive tells the assembler to add the org (origin) value to the offset. This allows that when you far jump to a label with an unknown position (instead of hardcoding the position of the label), the offset will be calculated properly by the assembler considering the actual position of the code in RAM.

With the example above, the org directive is useful only for the far jump to protected mode and for the lgdt instruction. You see that the far jump is disassembled to the line `00000014  EA197C0800        jmp 0x8:0x7c19`. The far jump's address is absolute meaning that the address is calculated directly. If you don't have the org directive, the disassembled far jump will instead be `jmp 0x8:0x19`. This is not the right address. It would jump to address 0x19 which doesn't work with the fact that your bootloader code will be loaded at 0x7c00. You need to tell the assembler to add 0x7c00 to all absolute addresses (mostly far jumps and the lgdt instruction).

Comment: thank you! this is exacty what i've been looking for!